# read_insights permission for business account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I searched for an answer to this question, and some came close, but they didn't quite answer it.

I'm building/maintaining an app that allows businesses to manage their social media accounts. So for facebook, the user gives permissions and we show the pages they manage. Then they choose one, and we use the page's access token to query the facebook API to do all kinds of things.

Now, this all works great, but some users have a business account for facebook, where they manage their pages with. This also works, but...

We would like to ask for read_insights permissions, to show the reach of the posts they created and that sort of things. But for some reason the facebook login/permissions screen doesn't work  if the user is logged in with a business account and the read_insights permission is requested (it works great with a normal account, or without the read_insights permissions).

Is there a way to fix this? We basically need the connection to work, regardless the type of facebook account you have. As long as you're the admin of a page, our app ought to work.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your problem? i am having similar issues